# How can I extract text between tags using HTML::Parser?

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I need to do some parse some data off webpages. How do I extract text between tags using HTML::Parser?

Consider the following sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

my $find_title = HTML::Parser->new(
    api_version => 3,
    start_h => [ 
        sub {
             my ($tag, $attr) = @_;
             print Dumper \@_;
            }, 
        'tag'
               ],
  );

my $html = join '',
    "<html><head><title>Extract me!</title></head><body>",
    (map { qq(<a href="http://$_.com">$_</a>) } qw/foo bar baz/),
    "</body></html>";

$find_title->report_tags('title');
$find_title->parse($html);
```

How do I fix this so I can extract the title? This only extracts the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `text_h` handler to collect the text, and an `end_h` handler to do something when the `</title>` tag appears (at which point the text inside the tag has been collected).

HTML::Parser is a fairly low-level module, you may be happier with one of the many modules built on top of it, like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) or [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTokeParser).

For example, [HTML::HeadParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aHeadParser) makes extracting the title trivial:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::HeadParser;

my $html = join '',
    "<html><head><title>Extract me!</title></head><body>",
    (map { qq(<a href="http://$_.com">$_</a>) } qw/foo bar baz/),
    "</body></html>";

my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new;
$p->parse($html);

my $title = $p->header('Title');
```